I can't find the reason my snmpv3 traps aren't getting logged on RHEL 8.9
I'm setting up some trap receivers to collect snmpv3 traps.
I configured it and got it working as desired in DEV1.
Created a tar file and copied it to DEV2, extracted it, recycled snmptrapds and snmpd and it works as desired.
Copied the tar file to UAT, extracted it, recycled snmptrad & snmpd and it works as desired.
Copied the tar file to PROD1, extracted it, recycled snmptrapd and snmpd and no traps logged.
I even copied the tar from PROD1 back to UAT, extracted it and it still works.
For reference, here are the files I configured and copied from server to server
etc/scripts/GetEngineID.sh
etc/scripts/DeviceList.csv
etc/snmp/snmp.conf
etc/snmp/snmpd.conf
etc/snmp/snmptrapd.conf
etc/sysconfig/snmpd
etc/sysconfig/snmptrapd

The first two are my script to get the client EngineID's and the list of clients.
Here are the snmp related RPM packages installed.
net-snmp.x86_64                          1:5.8-28.el8
net-snmp-agent-libs.x86_64               1:5.8-28.el8
net-snmp-devel.x86_64                    1:5.8-28.el8
net-snmp-libs.x86_64                     1:5.8-28.el8
net-snmp-utils.x86_64                    1:5.8-28.el8
rsyslog-mmsnmptrapd.x86_64               8.2102.0-15.el8

All servers are the same build, RHEL 8.9.
They all work fine with snmpv1 and snmpv2c traps.
Anyone see anything I might be missing, or what might cause this? Again, all the snmp configuration files are the same across all servers.
Regards,
Tom
